# Unbound Local Error with my variables and function, enemy fight

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a code for a little game where you go to a cave and have multiple branches, your character is supposed to attack an enemy, but the variable for the health of the enemy wont update and shows an error every time I attack. I have tried putting the code inside the function as well.
Here is my script for the fight sequence. Also please note I am a novice coder.

```
    boss = 20
    player = 20
    def boss_battle():
      boss_fight = input("Will you attack from the left, middle, or right? ").lower()
      if boss_fight == "left":
        boss = boss - 3
        player = player - 3
        print("Boss has taken 3 damamge, you have also taken 3 damage")
        boss_battle()
      elif boss_fight == "right":
        random_hit = random.randint(1,6)
        if random_hit > 3:
          boss = boss - 7
          print("The enemy has taken 7 damage!! ")
          boss_battle()
        elif random_hit < 3:
          player = player - 7
          print("You missed! You have taken 7 damage! ")
          boss_battle()
      elif boss_fight == "middle":
        print("You missed! You take 2 damage. ")
        player = player - 2
        boss_battle()
      else:
        print("Please select a valid option")
        boss_battle()
      if boss == 0:
        print("You killed the enemy, you take the gold and lavish in the riches!")
      elif player == 0:
        print("You died!")
        cave_game()
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [edit] your question to include the steps you're entering to cause the error, and the full traceback of the error, as that contains important information

Comment: exit condition should be boss <= 0 and player <= 0. you subtract more than 1 at a time.This article can explain how to use local, globals and unbound https://towardsdatascience.com/global-local-and-nonlocal-variables-in-python-6b11c20d73b0

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are in a local scope, so they can't be modified by your function. You need to put them in a global scope. Use the `global` keyword to do this.

**Full code:**

```py
boss = 20
player = 20
def boss_battle():
    global boss
    global player
    boss_fight = input("Will you attack from the left, middle, or right? ").lower()
    if boss_fight == "left":
        boss = boss - 3
        player = player - 3
        print("Boss has taken 3 damamge, you have also taken 3 damage")
        boss_battle()
    elif boss_fight == "right":
        random_hit = (random.randint(1,6))
        if random_hit > 3:
            boss = boss - 7
            print("The enemy has taken 7 damage!! ")
            boss_battle()
        elif random_hit < 3:
            player = player - 7
            print("YOU MISSED! You have taken 7 damage! ")
            boss_battle()
    elif boss_fight == "middle":
        print("You missed! You take 2 damage. ")
        player = player - 2
        boss_battle()
    else:
        print("Please select a valid option")
        boss_battle()
    if boss == 0:
        print("You killed the enemy, you take the gold and lavish in the riches!")
    elif player == 0:
        print("You died!")
        cave_game()
```